# Using MaterialDesignThemes DrawerHost

Tags: c#, visual-studio, material-design

Please could someone assist me in trying to figure this out.

I have created a menu on a WPF page called `DashView.xaml`
this menu has buttons on it going down and I would like to know how to get the `BottomDrawerContent` to be visible once I click on a button.

Below I have given the code that is in `DashView.xaml`

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost x:Name="hostSales" >
    <materialDesign:DrawerHost x:Name="SalesDrawerHost" Content="Sales" Foreground="GhostWhite"
                               FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="22" BottomDrawerCloseOnClickAway="True"
                               Cursor="Hand" Width="200" Height="30" ToggleButton.Checked="chkSalesBt1">
    
                        <materialDesign:DrawerHost.BottomDrawerContent x:Uid="dashSalesBt1">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="stkSalesBt1">
                                <Button Content="Record Sales" Foreground="GhostWhite" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                                <Button Content="Recent Sales" Foreground="GhostWhite" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </materialDesign:DrawerHost.BottomDrawerContent>
                        
    </materialDesign:DrawerHost>
</materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

I do have a class called DashClass.cs

Just not sure what I am meant to put in it or how I am meant to get the execution to show the `BottomDrawerContent`

Comment: Can you give more code? For example, your `dashSalesBt1` and `stkSalesBt1`.

Comment: basically the dashSalesBt1 is a button in the drop down menu and does nothing yet and the stkSalesBt1 is the stackpanel that holds the buttons of the drop down menu

Answer (score 1):

Yout need a tooglebutton:

```
<ToggleButton
    x:Name="menuToggler" 
    Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignHamburgerToggleButton}" />`
```

and in the DrawerHost use **IsLeftDrawerOpen**

```
<materialDesign:DrawerHost 
    x:Name="SalesDrawerHost" 
    Content="Sales" 
    Foreground="GhostWhite"
    FontWeight="Bold" 
    FontSize="22" 
    BottomDrawerCloseOnClickAway="True"
    Cursor="Hand" 
    Width="200" 
    Height="30"
    IsBottomDrawerOpen="{Binding ElementName=menuToggler, Path=IsChecked}">

    <materialDesign:DrawerHost.BottomDrawerContent x:Uid="dashSalesBt1">
       <StackPanel x:Name="stkSalesBt1">
           <Button Content="Record Sales" Foreground="GhostWhite" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
           <Button Content="Recent Sales" Foreground="GhostWhite" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
       </StackPanel>
    </materialDesign:DrawerHost.BottomDrawerContent>
</materialDesign:DrawerHost>
```